# Why self hosted integration runtime in azure data factory require 80gb space?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I Have a server that has low disk space let say around 15GB free space and I want to install this self-hosted runtime service in that but as per the minimum system configuration, it says you should have 80GB free disk space so wanted to understand for which purpose azure data factory integration service require this much of space and if I go with the installation in less disk space what will be the consequences I have to face thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

Hi according to the documentation,

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39717

It's a pre requisite to have 80GB space during installation. If not, it's not going to be installed successfully.

Comment: Yes, that I know but just wondering for what purpose it requires 80 GB of space.